# Zend Framework - "Invalid controller specified"

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with setting up my Zend Framework application on live server. It works alright on localhost.

My live server address where I have the application is:

http://www.domainname.com/new/

Everything is OK until I try to access my admin module at URL http://www.domainname.com/new/admin , then I get the error below.

Any ideas?

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (index)
Stack trace:

#0 /data/www/www.domainname.com/public_html/new/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /data/www/www.domainname.com/public_html/new/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /data/www/www.domainname.com/public_html/new/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /data/www/www.domainname.com/public_html/new/index.php(27): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'module' => 'admin',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

Include paths in index.php are set correctly (library and everything else is loaded), index.php file here:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

set_include_path('library');

// Define upload path
if (!defined('UPLOAD_PATH'))
        define('UPLOAD_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/upload/');

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Bootstrap.php file:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initDoctype(){
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    }

    protected function _initTimeZone(){
        $date = $this->getOption('date');
        date_default_timezone_set($date['timezone']);
    }

    protected function _initLayoutHelper(){
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
            new Jakub_Controller_Action_Helper_LayoutLoader());
    }

    protected function _initFlashMessenger(){
        $flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');

        if ($flashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
            $view = $this->getResource('view');
            $view->messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
        }
    }

    protected function _initAuth(){
        $this->bootstrap('session');
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $view = $this->getResource('view');
            $view->user = $auth->getIdentity();
        }

        return $auth;
    }
}
```

Application.ini file:

```
[production]
webhost = "http://www.domainname.com/new"

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

date.timezone = "Europe/Bratislava"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

appnamespace = "Application"
autoloadernamespaces.nette = "Nette_"
autoloadernamespaces.jakub = "Jakub_"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.view[] =
resources.view.helperPath.App_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"

resources.modules[] =

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/default/"
resources.layout.layout = default

admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/layouts/scripts/base/"
admin.resources.layout.layout = default

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
webhost = "http://domainname"

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your admin module folder, check that IndexController.php exists within the "controllers" sub-directory.

If it does, then open IndexController.php and ensure that the class declaration does indeed declare the class "IndexController" (a common copy+paste pitfall)

Edit: Controller name should be Admin_IndexController, not just IndexController

Comment: Everything in controller is fine, it exists, name is "class Admin_IndexController".

Comment: And the file name is indexController.php, the application works alright on localhost, so the problem will be in paths probably or some configuration.

Comment: Class name should be IndexController, not Admin_IndexController.

Comment: Actually, my original comment is incorrect -- it should be Admin_IndexController

Comment: The filename should be IndexController.php (note the first capital). On windows it works. On Unix is the file system case sensitive and therefore it fails.

Answer (score 0):

try in your application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
```

I also have this in my application.ini for my module app:

```
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
```

also does each module have it's own bootstrap?

```
<?php

class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {
    //put your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using an authetication controller my collegue prepared and I had the same problem, and I found the problem in the redirect of the controller.

```
if (!$this->_acl->isAllowed(Zend_Registry::get('user_role'), $module . ':' . $controller, $action)) {
$request->setModuleName('default')->setControllerName('authentication')->setActionName('login');}
```

This basically checkes if you are logged in and if you have the access rights to go to the specified controller, and if not, it redirects you to (in this case) default/authenticaion/index
Unfortunately the redirect parameters are not displayed in the error message.
I realized I do not have the controller I am redirecting to ready, so in some cases it might be the same problem.